# What's the difference between these two linked list constructor?

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

```
 class ListNode {
     int val;
     ListNode next;
     ListNode(int x) {
         val = x;
         next = null;
     }
 }
```

```
  static class LinkedList {
    int value;
    LinkedList next = null;

    public LinkedList(int value) {
      this.value = value;
    }
  }
```

I'm new to programming and now practicing algorithms. And I see these two different versions of the constructor in various websites. Can someone give me some examples or use-cases of how to use these constructors?

Answer (score 1):

The specific versions you present boil down to the same thing. Both have a field storing the current node's value (`val` and `value`). Likewise, both have a reference to the next node (`next`) that is `null` at initialization time.

There's isn't any functional difference between those two versions, apart from the `static` vs. non-`static` class and `public` vs `package-private` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Both give the same result, but it depends on each programmer to use them, a good practice that many programmers choose is to leave the variables initially empty and give their values in the constructors or methods. Hugs!